# Redirecting to JSP in javascript not working (using Spring MVC)

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

What i want is on Confirm of Javascript i want to redirect to a Redirect.JSP page.
and that jsp page Contains a code to Redirect to HomePage.jsp that is achieved using Spring MVC.

Now its getting Redirected to Redirect.jsp but from internally its not redirecting it to HomePage.jsp.
If i refresh the Page then only it gets Redirected.

My Code..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

if (confirm("Data Saved Successfully")) {
    window.location.href("http://localhost:8383/AdminPricingModule/Redirect.jsp");
}

</script>
```

and code for Redirect.jsp

```
<body >
    <% response.sendRedirect("startPublish.htm");%>
</body>
```

the code above Rediercts to HomePage using SpringMVC.
Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use scriptlets, do the redirect in your controller.

```
public String myMethod(){
return "redirect:startPublish.htm";
}
```

Comment: the page in which i am writing the script its a jsp Page not the controller.

Comment: @Azuu yeah thats why I said don't do that

Comment: but still i want to show a messagebox on saving data and then redirect to jsp page

Comment: Show whatever message you want, then, instead of redirecting to a jsp, redirect to a .htm.